# multi-repository graphql types with local npm link

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, graphql-js

Given 2 repositories `user-repo` and `project-repo`, I define `UserType` in the `user-repo`, and in package.json of `project-repo` I do this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "user-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com/me/user-repo"
}
```

and everything works (`UserType` loads in `project-repo`).
However if I link the repo locally like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "user-repo": "file:../../user-repo"
}
```

`UserType instanceof GraphQLObjectType` returns *false*. And it's only the graphql types that are acting up. Everything else like models is getting loaded just fine.

I've tried npm linking (`npm link user-repo`), doing it both the require and import ways, and it didn't help.
Any ideas?

Comment: what is `typeof UserType`?

Comment: @IonutAchim GraphQLObjectType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was also discussed in `graphql-js` issue tracker:

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1091#issuecomment-349874772

Answer by FB developer @leebyron:

> Unfortunately npm link is pretty broken, though I'm surprised using a file path as a dependency didn't work for you.
>
> This issue occurs when there are multiple instances of graphql-js in your node_modules directory. npm-link works by creating symlink to another directory, if that other directory also has a node_modules folder with graphql-js within it, then you'll have multiple copies.
>
> When I develop in this way, I usually set up a script which cp's my sub-project's built source directly into the main project's node_modules directory, avoiding any filesystem symlinking hyjinx.

We ended up doing this: common code is no longer a npm package, we use symlink to map common code directory in each application directory and import/require same way as any application module.

Hint for those using docker: you will not be able to put common code into the container this way, docker forbids symlinks. To go around this you can copy the common code in the app temporary directory, build container and remove temporary directory afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here I go, I'm not entirely sure but I'm betting on the fact that `instanceof` is kinda tricky and I'm imagining the following scenario:

You build your schema inside `user-repo` and you run the check in `project-repo`. Both repos have their own `graphql` module dependency installed meaning that `GraphQLObjectType` constructor in `user-repo` is different from the one in `project-repo`, that's why `instanceof` returns false. You can confirm it's actually ok by doing `UserType.contructor.name === 'GraphQLObjectType'` and that should be true.

A solution would be to import `GraphQLObject` from the same module. See if that works.

Edited this answer as previously I've provided a solution with webpack aliasing, but that doesn't apply on backend.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately were not using webpack for the backend

Comment: Lol, true :)) I completely forgot. Try to import GraphQLObjectType from the same package, with the entire path